# BroadcastReceiver is not called in Android >= Api 26

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

BroadcastReceiver ist not working for any action in Api 26 or higher, according to documentation implicit actions are blocked, but not boot_completed. I tested with Android 19, 24, 26 and 28.

Here is my receiver declaration:

```
<receiver
        android:name="de.com.limto.limto1.broadcastReceiver"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and here my permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and here my receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Log.d(BROADCAST_RECEIVER,intent.getAction());
        lib.appendLog(intent.getAction(),context);
        lib.ShowToast(context, BROADCAST);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (service != null) {
                try {
                    service.stop();
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(BROADCAST_RECEIVER,throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                }
            }
        } else {
            /*if (service != null) return;
            Intent serviceIntent;
            serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LimindoService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(BOOT, true);
            */
            LimindoService.ccontext = context;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                //context.startService(serviceIntent);
                lib.scheduleJob(context);
            } else {
                //context.startService(serviceIntent);
                startServiceByAlarm(context);
            }


        }
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        lib.appendLog(ex.getMessage(), context);
        Log.e(BROADCAST_RECEIVER,null,ex);
        lib.ShowToast(context, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This behaviour is happening only on some devices with api >= 26 ... This was caused by the phone settings: Starting the service on boot was disabled in the settings.

Comment: What is the solution please?

Comment: enable start background service in settings

Comment: Which settings screen?

Comment: android >= 26 Settings for each app you can allow or prohibit background services.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast doesn't have category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`, removing the category should fix the problem.

Comment: This makes no difference. If I call am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED onReceive is not being called....

Comment: @Hans-MartinGoebel You should send `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` not `android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Although this is a [protected-broadcast](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#37), meaning that only the system can send it, I'm not sure it's possible to send it via shell uid or not.

Comment: @Hans-MartinGoebel Also note that Android won't send implicit broadcast intents to newly installed apps or force closed ones until user explicitly opens one of its Activities, or an explicit intent has been previously sent to this app.

Comment: only root can send android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and I don't have a rooted device. I also registered android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED and it is being called in devices < api 26. I also restarted the device and nothing is being written to the log file. And I did open the app before.

Comment: @Hans-MartinGoebel Where's the log file? Before user unlocks the device, storage may be encrypted and not accessible to your app. Does your app really need `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED`? I tested the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast on a device having O+, it woks fine. My `<intent-filer>` has only one `<action>` (`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`) and without `<category>`.

Comment: My IntentFilter is now:

<receiver
            android:name="de.com.limto.limto1.broadcastReceiver"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

and still onReceive is not called on startup.

Comment: I also made a test app and onReceive gets called with API 25 but does not get called with API 26......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205839/discussion-between-hans-martin-goebel-and-frogatto).